# STDERR output in asterisk cli

Tags: perl, asterisk, stderr

How can i see the output to STDERR in asterisk CLI? I found that the stderr output is visible in the original asterisk terminal but cannot be seen in the cli which is obtained by asterisk -cvvvvvvvvvr. I want to see the error message of my perl agi script (warn "text") .

Answer (score 1):

You can't see it.

Reason: stderror sended to linux stderror handler of asterisk process. When you connect to asterisk console, you have other proccess which have other stderror handler.

So if you want see errors, you need setup your asterisk startup script to store that errors in some file. Or edit default script /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk to suite your need.

Actualy if you read AGI specification you can see,that your script have send error messages to stdout,preferable using WARNING agi function. That can be archived by redirecting stderror to stdout in script or by writing special handler/wrapper.